# Memcached setup with cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, memcached, cakephp-3.0

I am setting up memcache setup with cakephp3. I added below in config/app.php

```
'Cache' => [
   'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Cache\Engine\MemcachedEngine',            
    ],
]
```

On the top of the controller I added 
    use Cake\Cache\Cache;
    use Cake\Cache\CacheEngine;
    use Cake\Cache\CacheRegistry;

But when I used any function of memcache like Cache::write('variable','value'); etc
It is giving me error 
" Error: Cache engine Cake\Cache\Engine\MemcachedEngine is not properly configured.  "

The memcached is installed on server.. here is the output

```
/etc/php.d/memcache.ini,
memcache
memcache support => enabled
memcache.allow_failover => 1 => 1
memcache.chunk_size => 32768 => 32768
memcache.compress_threshold => 20000 => 20000
memcache.default_port => 11211 => 11211
memcache.hash_function => crc32 => crc32
memcache.hash_strategy => consistent => consistent
memcache.lock_timeout => 15 => 15
memcache.max_failover_attempts => 20 => 20
memcache.protocol => ascii => ascii
memcache.redundancy => 1 => 1
memcache.session_redundancy => 2 => 2
```

Please let me know what is the remaining in configuration. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### Wrong extension

There are two php extensions related to memcache:

- [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) (older)
- [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) (newer, more features)

The CakePHP Memcached driver [relies on memcacheD](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Cache/Engine/MemcachedEngine.php#L104-L106):

```
if (!extension_loaded('memcached')) {
    return false;
}
```

Which [will result in that error message](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Cache/CacheRegistry.php#L89-L93) if it's missing:

```
if (!$instance->init($config)) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
        sprintf('Cache engine %s is not properly configured.', get_class($instance))
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any other thing that I need to put in configuration file? I have already wrote above what I write in app.php. Is that correct?

Comment: I have installed memcached and its still not working. Is there any other configuration need to add/remove in configuration.

Comment: in phpinfo.. session.save_handler files memcached. on command line i tried [root@server ~]#  memcached-tool 127.0.0.1 stats
#127.0.0.1:11211   Field       Value
         accepting_conns           1
               auth_cmds           0
             auth_errors           0
                   bytes           0
              bytes_read          14

and some more lines.. In app.php I used same as above. But engine Cake\Cache\Engine\MemcachedEngine is not properly configured.

Comment: Determine why [the init method](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Cache/Engine/MemcachedEngine.php#L102-L186) returns false - I cannot/willnot guess why your install doesn't work. The above comment does not confirm to me the memcached extension is installed.

Comment: Can you please give me all steps that I need to follow for server (centos 6.3) and in cakephp3 and in other files if required.

Comment: How to install memcached is not in the scope of this question - can you please debug and find out why your install doesn't work =)?

Comment: Its working now.. actually we need to install both memcache and memcached to work it properly. The memcached is a demon but memcache need for php.Thanks